# A nonparametric test for multivariate paired data? (i.e. multivariate version of wilcoxon signed-rank test?)

Tags: multivariate-analysis, nonparametric, paired-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank, tukey-depth

I have a set of datasets that have undergone 6 different pre-processing approaches prior to undergoing dimensionality reduction with two different algorithms, after which I score them for structure preservation - so a 40 samples(the datasets) x 6 variables(the different pre-processing approaches) matrix for each of the two dim reduction algorithms. I am trying to determine if there is a significant difference in the mean or median performance of the two algorithms overall. The data is not multivariate normal according to a [Henze-Zirkler test](https://pingouin-stats.org/generated/pingouin.multivariate_normality.html). I am not particularly strong with statistics but I believe if my data was not multivariate the test I would be applying is a wilcoxon rank-sign test.

In looking for a multivariate version of this, I can find many articles ([Jureckova & Kalina 2012](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.0450.pdf),[Li & Liu 2004](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-19/issue-4/New-Nonparametric-Tests-of-Multivariate-Locations-and-Scales-Using-Data/10.1214/088342304000000594.full),[Wang et al. 2015](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4734767/),[Pawar & Shirke 2018](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00949655.2019.1590577), [Jiang et al. 2018](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0195894), [Dehghan & Faridrohani 2021](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/anzs.12328), etc.), but none that provide an implementation in R, Python or Matlab, and I am not confident enough in my understanding of the texts to effectively implement the tests myself. The M-based test in Li & Liu et al. 2004 seemed particularly promising as it is frequently discussed in other articles and in testbooks, but even this I cannot find any implementation of.

The closest implemented test I have found is the depth based multivariate Wilcoxon rank-sum test  implemented in [DepthProc](https://rdrr.io/rforge/DepthProc/man/mWilcoxonTest.html). However my understanding is that this is a test for difference in scale/distribution rather than for location via mean or median. I am also unsure of whether this adaptation would still require the samples to be independent, which they are not for my data.

It is straightforward for me to adapt this code to use a wilcoxon rank-sign test as opposed to a rank-sum test on the depth values obtained for each group, but the fact that no one seems to have implemented this option already makes me hesitate in whether the use of depth values (something I am also unfamiliar with) somehow makes this inappropriate?

If anyone could advise me on whether applying a depth-based wilcoxon rank-sign test would be problematic, or whether there is some other test or implementation or a multivariate wilcoxon rank-sign that I am missing, that would be fantastic.

Thank you!